# Graphviz splines=false has no effect on undirected graph with bi-directional a -- b/b -- a edges

Tags: graph, graphviz, splines

I am drawing an undirected graph with Graphviz that has redundant edges, (e.g. A -- B and B -- A).  I would like to see only one line between the two vertices, regardless of whether there is a redundant reverse edge in the data.  My question is, is there a way to do this with Graphviz, without having to use some other tool/code first to remove the redundant edges?  I have tried `graph [splines=false];` without any success.  Below is a minimal example:

```
graph G {
    graph [splines=false];
    node [shape=point];
    a -- b;
    b -- a;
}
```

And the output:

[image]

What I *want* as output is:

[image]

despite the redundant edges that may exist in the specified graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "strict graph G { ... }"

A strict graph or digraph disallows parallel edges.

Stephen North  north@graphviz.org

Comment: I haen't tried this myself as I've been working on other projects, but for now I will mark this as the accepted answer as it sounds most relevant.

Answer (score 3):

You may try setting [`nodesep`](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dnodesep) to 0 :

> ... this **affects the spacing between** loops on a single node, or **multiedges** between a pair of nodes.

Not sure if nodesep is completely set to 0, because in the documentation the minimum value indicated is 0.02. A quick test seems to be ok, though.